Index sub-entry for loop newcommand
I have a problem with sub-entries in a for loop. My MWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=P, title=P, columns=2]

\newcommand{\Ka}{K1 -- First item K}
\newcommand{\Kb}{K2 -- Second item K}
\newcommand{\Pa}{P1 - First item P}
\newcommand{\Pb}{P2 - Second item P}

\newcommand{\perf}[3]{%
    \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}
    \foreach \x in {#3} {%  
       \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}!\detokenize{\x}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\perf{P}{\Pb}{\Ka,\Kb} %-> does not work for subentry

% by hand it works
\lipsum[1-6]
\index[P]{\Pa}
\index[P]{\Pa!\Ka}
\index[P]{\Pa!\Kb}

\printindex[P]
\end{document}

I have tried several options that worked for the main entry : \detokenize, \string, \usebox. But I cannot manage to do anything about the sub-entries. I have left in the code a version with \detokenize for the sub-entry even though I understand that it can't work. If it's something about \expandafter, I'm afraid that I've never understood it, but I'm pretty sure someone could explain it to me. Of course, I can use over for loop or LaTeX3 syntax.
Any help would be appreciated.

Your first problem is, that \foreach is undefined. So it seems a package or a command definition is missing. Please try to fix this. And IMHO you don't want to write \x to the index, but maybe the first expansion of \x.

Currently you are writing \x to the raw index. But IMHO you want to write the first expansion of \x. So you need to do one expansion before \detokenize it, e.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}% added for one possible definition of \foreach, which was undefined in your example
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=P, title=P, columns=2]

\newcommand{\Ka}{K1 -- First item K}
\newcommand{\Kb}{K2 -- Second item K}
\newcommand{\Pa}{P1 - First item P}
\newcommand{\Pb}{P2 - Second item P}

\newcommand{\perf}[3]{%
    \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}}% commenting eol added
    \foreach \x in {#3} {%  
       \index[#1]{\detokenize{#2}!\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\x}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\perf{P}{\Pb}{\Ka,\Kb} %-> does not work for subentry

% by hand it works
\lipsum[1-6]
\index[P]{\Pa}
\index[P]{\Pa!\Ka}
\index[P]{\Pa!\Kb}

\printindex[P]
\end{document}

In the example the first \expandafter is used to expand the token after \detokenize after expanding \detokenize once. The second \expandafter is used to also expand the \x after expanding the { once. This results in expanding \x once before detokenizing it.


Sorry for the missing \usepackage{tikz} and thanks for your quick reply! I was pretty sure it was something to do with \expandafter, but I couldn't code it.  I just want to say that this forum is really helpful.

\expandafter is used to expand the next but one token. So with \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\x} the result of the first \expandafter is the next token, which is \detokenize, plus the toplevel-expansion of the next but one token, which is the second \expandafter, while the toplevel-expansion of the second \expandafter is { plus the toplevel-expansion of \x.

\detokenize processes ⟨general text⟩. TeX doesn't suppress expansion while scanning for a ⟨general text⟩'s first implicit or explicit character token of category 1. (Category 1 is "begin group".) Therefore \detokenize\expandafter{\x} has the same effect as \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\x}. But I wouldn't use \detokenize at all because with index-entries you don't want things to be sorted in the place where the name of the control sequence token would be sorted by which they were produced.

I'd not use \foreach.
With \clist_map_inline:nn you process one by one the comma separated items and refer to them as #1; in this case you need ##1 because you're in a definition.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex[name=P, title=P, columns=2]

\newcommand{\Ka}{K1 -- First item K}
\newcommand{\Kb}{K2 -- Second item K}
\newcommand{\Pa}{P1 -- First item P}
\newcommand{\Pb}{P2 -- Second item P}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\perf}{O{}mm}
 {
  \index[#1]{\tl_to_str:n{#2}}
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#3}
   {
    \index[#1]{\tl_to_str:n {#2!##1}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\perf[P]{\Pa}{\Ka,\Kb}
\perf[P]{\Pb}{\Ka,\Kb}

\printindex[P]

\end{document}

I made the first argument to \perf optional just like the standard for \index (with imakeidx).

I left \detokenize, which in expl3 is \tl_to_str:n, although I don't think it's necessary. Here's what you get in the .idx file without \tl_to_str:n:
\indexentry{P1 -- First item P}{1}
\indexentry{P1 -- First item P!K1 -- First item K}{1}
\indexentry{P1 -- First item P!K2 -- Second item K}{1}
\indexentry{P2 -- Second item P}{1}
\indexentry{P2 -- Second item P!K1 -- First item K}{1}
\indexentry{P2 -- Second item P!K2 -- Second item K}{1}

With \tl_to_str:n you get instead
\indexentry{\Pa }{1}
\indexentry{\Pa !\Ka }{1}
\indexentry{\Pa !\Kb }{1}
\indexentry{\Pb }{1}
\indexentry{\Pb !\Ka }{1}
\indexentry{\Pb !\Kb }{1}

which would affect the sorting.

Another amazing solution! I definitely need to learn LaTeX3.
